# GLSurfaceView parent is null even though it is nested in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, android-linearlayout

I have a custom view called GLView that extends the GLSurfaceView class. Inside of this GLView I want to access the other TextView that is contained in a parent Linear Layout. When I call this.getParent it returns NULL, so I looked and eclipse indeed says that mparent is null. does anyone know why?

Activity class that calls the View

```
package org.kizik.WLTBO;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;




import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WholettheballoutActivity extends Activity {
   GLView view;



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.score);
      view = (GLView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);


   // You can use a FrameLayout to hold the surface view
      /*FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
      frameLayout.addView(view);

      // Then create a layout to hold everything, for example a RelativeLayout
      RelativeLayout relativeLayout= new RelativeLayout(this);
      relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
      relativeLayout.addView(score);
      setContentView(relativeLayout);*/
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       view.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       view.onResume();
   }
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent" >


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text = "Points 12345 Time:"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:textSize="22sp"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <org.kizik.WLTBO.GLView
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>        

</LinearLayout>
```

Probably not needed but here are the constructors within the GLView class

```
public GLView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      // Uncomment this to turn on error-checking and logging
      //setDebugFlags(DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
      renderer = new GLRenderer(context, view);
      setRenderer(renderer);
   }

   public GLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

       super(context,attrs);
       view = this.getParent();

       renderer = new GLRenderer(context, view);
       setRenderer(renderer);

   }
```

Comment: how are you debugging, on what device? I went crazy trying to figure out a similar issue with opencv on android. It turned out that due to some hardware issues, Motorola devices like droid X would always crash... Nexus S was fine though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try expanding the layout first before you do `setContentView()` in activity. You can then check whether the default layout behavior is attaching the GLSurfaceView to the LinearLayout:

```
View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main,null,false);
view = (GlView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
if(view.getParent()==null || !view.getParent() instanceof View ){
    // throw new Exception("GLView had no parent or wrong parent");
} else {
    setContentView(parentView);
}
```

---

You can't actually change the parent view (the linear layout) or any other views in your renderer from inside the `onDraw()`, `onSurfaceChanged()` or `onSurfaceCreated()` methods as they are all called by the GL thread. Only the main/UI thread (the one that calls `onCreate()` in your activity) can change the UI. If you tried for example to do `((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Some text");` in `onSurfaceCreated()`, it would cause an exception

A better way to do this would be to set the renderer from inside the activity:

```
public class WholettheballoutActivity extends Activity {


    GLView view;
    GLRenderer renderer;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score);
        view = (GLView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
        LinearLayout parentView = findViewById(R.id.parent);

        // Handler declaration goes in UI thread
        Handler handle = new Handler(new Handler.Callback(){

            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg){
                // message is handled by the UI thread

                TextView tv = WholettheballoutActivity .this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                tv.setText("You Rock!");

                return true;

            }


        });

        renderer = new GLRenderer(context, parent, handler);
        view.setRenderer(renderer);

    }

}
```

Then in renderer:

```
public class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    View parent;
    Context context;
    Handler handler;

    public GLRenderer(Context context, View parent, Handler handler){
        this.context = context;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.handler = handler;

    }

    public void onDraw(GL10 gl){

        // drawing etc


        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }

}
```

Anything inside the handleMessage method of a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) gets queued for the UI thread to execute next time it loops round. There are [other ways to pass messages between other threads and the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), but this one although not immediately obvious, makes most sense for non-UI threads making single asynchronous updates to the UI

EDIT: Handler has to be declared in the thread it is to be used in (unless you're doing something funky [see here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/))

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the long wait time. I have tried the fix above where the only thing I had to change was making the renderer in the activity equal to new glrenderer(this, parentView). I am having problems though when I try and do the view.setrenderer(renderer). when debugging it says that the source is not found.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that I can only set the renderer once, so i commented out the setrenderer that was in the glview constructor. Now, however, I get an error that occurs when the handler is being set in the ondraw method. it crashes the program.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Actually I was wrong about Handler always being called in the UI thread. It is called from the thread where it was declared. In otherwords, declare a handler in `onCreate()`, and then pass it into the renderer constructor. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

`Gets the parent of this view. Note that the parent is a ViewParent and` **`not necessarily a View.`**

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I had it typecasted. but even so it does not return a ViewParent either